# Call to undefined function openssl_pkey_new()?

Tags: php, openssl

I am trying to use phpwebsoket Wrench under WAMP, with php 5.3.13, but the openssl_pkey_new function is undefined. I have enabled php open ssl extension and the the apache ssl module, but sure I a missing something more. any help please?

Comment: Yes of course. I restart all services.

Comment: Try checking the [PHP instalation docs](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php) for OpenSSL to make sure you did everything right to enable the extension.

Comment: I have done the initiall part, I have added the php dir to the windows PATH. I have not yet configure the openssl.conf. But it is strange, is this mandatory for that function to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Make a PHP script containing:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());
```

Then run it on the server and check if in the output array there is a notice about the SSL extension, to make sure that it has been loaded probably.